# Unable to connect with Postgres with commad line

Tags: postgresql, cmd, psql

I want to connect with Postgres with a command-line (cmd). But when I enter this command in cmd `psql -U postgres postgres` ,cmd asks me for a password, but when I try to enter the password, my Keyboard doesn't work, only the enter Key is working. Can someone tells me why my keyboard stopped working when cmd asked me for a password?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For security purposes the console doesn't show the characters typed, have you tried typing the password and pressing enter?

(I had the exact same issue recently)